# Problem integrating ROS with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: ros, ide, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've tried to integrate ROS with eclipse following this [link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs). According to step no.2, I had to run "make eclipse-project" in my package directory, however, i got an error "make: *** No rule to make target `eclipse-project'.  Stop."

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11367/problem-integrating-ros-with-eclipse-indigo/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to integrate rosjava code or roscpp code?

The instructions for rosjava (in progress) are here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Build/Eclipse

For roscpp, your project needs to follow the standard package template, where the `Makefile` looks like:

```
 include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
```

And nothing more (i.e. the rest of your bulid is configured via CMake).  The above cmake.mk file declares the eclipse-project target.

If you don't wish to use the cmake.mk file, then you can grab the necessary Makefile rule from mk/cmake.mk and adapt it to your needs.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-09-29**:
@kwc: Thanks a lot anyway..

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-29**:
Most ROS packages use the include and then do all the build configuration in CMake.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-09-29**:
Yeah, that works by using that include..By the way, which way is the best practice between those two?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-29**:
Yes, but if you do that include, your Makefile cannot contain anything else -- it is a wrapper for invoking into CMake.  So, an alternative is to copy the 'eclipse-project' target out of cmake.mk instead, and put that directly into your Makefile.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-09-29**:
I didn't get you. Did you mean I have to include "include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk" in Makefile? As far as I know, it is not recommended to alter  the Makefile, to alter CMakeList.txt makes sense.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-29**:
see updated answer above then

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-09-29**:
roscpp, not rosjava.